# could not connect to server (FreeNAS server)

Tags: macos, freenas, afp

I have imported a volume and set its permission like this
[image]

then I created an AFP share like this
[image]

then I created an AFP service like this
[image]

but when I am trying to connect to server from Mac I am getting error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the beginning with things like this - can you ping the IP, is there a firewall, does the directory exist etc.

Comment: from the browser I can access the admin page of freenas, using http://192.168.0.101